# Agregar valores de una lista a los diccionarios en una lista de diccionarios

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo una lista de dicionarios y quiero agregar a cada diccionario un nuevo par clave valor que obtengo de otra lista separada.

Este es la lista de diccionarios:

```
arts = [{'Name':'Core', 'Id':20, 'Type':'MP', 'Power':10},
{'Name':'PVC', 'Id':19, 'Type':'MP', 'Power':2}]
```

Quiero lograr el siguiente resultado:

```
arts = [{'Name':'Core', 'Id':20, 'Type':'MP', 'Power':10, 'weight':120},
{'Name':'PVC', 'Id':19, 'Type':'MP', 'Power':2, 'weight':1500}]
```

Oteniendo el par weight:valor de una lista como esta:

```
weight = ['120', '1500']
```

Estoy intentando el siguiente codigo pero me arroja un error:

```
for elem in arts:
    for k in elem.items():
        elem['weight'] = [elem]
```

El error es:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Estoy usando Python 3.6
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta solución usa la función intrínsica `zip`, que junta dos o más iterables y te devuelve tuplas, donde cada componente viene de un iterable distinto.

Como ya no estamos iterando sobre el diccionario original, podemos modificarlo sin problemas.

```
arts = [{'Name':'Core', 'Id':20, 'Type':'MP', 'Power':10},
{'Name':'PVC', 'Id':19, 'Type':'MP', 'Power':2}]
weight = [120, 1500]

for (dicc, peso) in zip(arts, weight):
    dicc['weight'] = peso

print(arts)
```

produce:

```
[{'Name': 'Core', 'Id': 20, 'Type': 'MP', 'Power': 10, 'weight': 120}, {'Name': 'PVC', 'Id': 19, 'Type': 'MP', 'Power': 2, 'weight': 1500}]
```

Comment: Era la misma que le iba a poner, jejeje. Solo faltaría transformarlos a integer, por si quieres añadirlo.

Comment: Sería cosa de transformar la lista de pesos a una lista de enteros ...

Comment: @Candid Moe  Excelente me has ayudado. Gracias!

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Gracias por el aporte!!